# Replacing words in Wordpress or theme (not in content)

Tags: customization

I am struggling to find some words that are appearing in the Wordpress (or theme). In particular I cannot find where the word 'by' is, as I need to replcae this word. This is the word 'by' that appears in the posts at the top of each post "date BY author". I need to replace the word 'by' for another word, but cannot find its location.

I have tried the following in settings.php of the theme, but it does not work:

```
function hpm_replace_text($translated_text) {
    switch ($translated_text) {

        case 'by' : // write the original string here
            $translated_text = 'por'; // make a change to it
            break;

    }

    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter('gettext', 'hpm_replace_text');
```

There are also other words, such as 'Categories', 'Replies' which I need to replace but cannot find where they are located.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These would be in your template.  The Template File Hierarchy can be found here, and can help locate the specific template for the page you are looking at:  https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

The plugin, Show Current Plugin, can also help:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/show-current-template/